# How to overload operators in C++ when declaring an Object as volatile

Tags: c++, class, object, operator-overloading, volatile

I need advice on volatile Objects. Here is my class

```
class A
{
private:
volatile unsigned long count;
public:

A & operator = (unsigned long number) { count = number; return *this; }
};
```

I create a instance of the class declared as volatile

```
volatile A myClass;
```

When I use the "=" operator to assign a value I get a compiler error

```
myClass = 5;
```

How do I have to cast the "this" pointer for this to work? Or is this even the problem?

Comment: Change it to `A& operator=(unsigned long) volatile`

Comment: Nope, already tried this error "binding 'volatile A' to reference of type 'A&' discards qualifiers"
Also you discarded "number"

Comment: In addition to the change proposed by @0x499602D2 you also have to return `volatile A&`.

Comment: Comments above notwithstanding, are you sure you need `volatile` here? It serves no good purpose in the provided code. I have suspicion you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: I use the code on a Microcontroller and use the Object in an interrupt Routine so I need it to be volatile. 
@FrançoisAndrieux
The cast is my problem, propably I`m doing it wrong... This is what I have now:
    A & operator = (unsigned long number) volatile { count = number; return (volatile A&)*this; }

Maybe someone would be so kind to show me the correct line of code :)

Edit: I don`t know how to write code in this comments :(

Comment: You don't need to have both `myClass` and `count` be volatile

Comment: @user3000289 No, do not cast away `volatile`. That is not what I meant. I meant make it `volatile A& operator=(unsigned long) volatile`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Awesome no compiler error anymore :) Thanks. You can write this as answer and I will accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you cannot call a non-`volatile` member function using a `volatile` pointer, reference or instance. This works like `const`, where you can only call `const` member functions if your object is `const` or if your pointer or reference is to a `const` qualified type. Must must therefor make your member function `volatile`.

The second problem is that, since your member function will be made `volatile`, the `this` pointer will also be `volatile`, meaning `*this` is a `volatile A &`. You will not be able to bind `*this` to `A &`, which is the return type of your operator, because `volatile A &` cannot bind to `A &`. Again, this is just like `const` where you couldn't bind `const A &` to `A &`. The solution is to change the return type of your operator to `volatile A &`.

Your operator should look like this :

```
volatile A & operator= (unsigned long number) volatile
{
    count = number; 
    return *this; 
}
```